# Is there any way to set usable variable for task trigger in deployment.toml?

Tags: triggers, wso2, task, wso2-esb, wso2-micro-integrator

as from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76697892/) i had to use environment variable to set interval for trigger in task , now i need to do same but instead of environment variable i need set same variable with same value in deployment.toml or elsewhere in my MI

i want set variable (i think it will be in deployment.toml) and use it as interval for my task trigger , so i will not need extra script to set environment variable on server where MI runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly read variables from the deployment.toml OOB. But here is how you can do the same with a properties file.

1. Create a file named `file.properties`in `MI_HOME/conf` directory and add the following content

```
TASK_FREQUENCY=* * * * *
```

2. Now in your task you should be able to read this property like below.

```xml
<trigger cron="$FILE:TASK_FREQUENCY"/>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="TestTask" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <trigger cron="$FILE:TASK_FREQUENCY"/>
    <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="injectTo" value="sequence"/>
    <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="message">
             <m0:getQuote xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
                <m0:request>
                   <m0:symbol>IBM</m0:symbol>
                </m0:request>
             </m0:getQuote>
          </property>
    <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="sequenceName" value="SeqMy"/>
</task>
```

Documentation [here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/injecting-parameters/#using-a-file).

Comment: can i use same method for transport header ?